# SQL PRIMARY KEY duplicate error same PRIMARY KEY across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting an error for having duplicate PRIMARY KEY. How can I use the same PRIMARY KEY across multiple tables? Showing how I can use it in the tables below would be very much appreciated. The error is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolati
onException: Duplicate entry 'Jam' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
    CREATE TABLE `skills` (
      `playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
      `testa` double default NULL,
      `testb` double default NULL,
      `testc` double default NULL,
      `testd` double default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`playerName`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

    CREATE TABLE `playerrights` (
      `playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
      `rank` int(2) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`playerName`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

    CREATE TABLE `skillsoverall` (
      `playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
      `lvl` int(11) default NULL,
      `xp` BIGINT(11) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`playerName`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: is the error in crating the tables or when you are adding data?

Comment: Kill the default that is zanny. No problem doing what you want. But a pk value can only occur once per table

Comment: it's when adding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't spread a primary key across multiple tables. You should have a table called `players` with one row per player, and these 3 tables should have a foreign key pointing to that.

The `playername` column can indeed be a primary key on each of the 3 tables you say you want it to be, but it's unlikely that's what you actually want. If you want there to be more than one row per player in any of these tables, then it shouldn't be a PK on those tables.

A primary key means exactly two things:

1. Unique (no 2 rows can have the same value for the column(s))
2. Not null

The error you got reflects the row you're inserting would violate #1.

The foreign key to the `players` table is what ensures referential integrity. Basically that nothing is stored for players that don't exist. And that players whose stats are stored aren't removed prior to their stats being removed, etc.

This is what your first table's DDL would look like with a FK to a `players` table (you should have such a table):

```
CREATE TABLE `skills` (
  `playerName` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `testa` double default NULL,
  `testb` double default NULL,
  `testc` double default NULL,
  `testd` double default NULL,

  index (playername),

  constraint fk_playername_rights
  foreign key (playername) references players (playername)
    on delete restrict
    on update restrict 

) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Note: you can change restrict to cascade if you want that effect (based on what you want to have happen if you attempt to change or remove a player in the players table)

Comment: Yes. The name of the foreign key has to be different on each table, but is otherwise the same. The name of the key immediately follows the word `constraint`. You could also leave out the `constraint xyz` part and let it assign a system generated name for you each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that you have the same primary key across tables, is that a given table can only have one instance of a given primary key. If you are adding data and try to add `Jam` while `Jam` is already in the table, it will throw the error you see. Your current schema only allows you to have one row per player. If that's the goal, then you might want to make them one big table.

However, I suspect what you really interested in is [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and have these three tables reference a table, i suspect called `players`. In which case, change

```
PRIMARY KEY (playerName)
```

to

```
FOREIGN KEY (playerName) REFERENCES players(playerName)
```